# user input to URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have some url and I need to replace some parts of it with user input from input type="text" and move to new link with button click. 
How can I place variables in URL ?

//some-url/trends.cgi?createimage&t1=**1412757517**&t2=**1412843917**&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=**SCP-3**&service=**MODIFICATION+TIME+EDR+FILES**&backtrack=4&zoom=4

i have function, but it place input at the end of url.

```
function redirect() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://google.com.ua/';

    document.myform.action=baseUrl + document.getElementById('url').value;
}

<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="redirect()">
    <input type="text" id="url">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build out manual query string parsers and constructors, an example would be like:

```
function parseQuery(qstr){
    var query = {};
    var a = qstr.split('&'); //take the passed query string and split it on &, creating an array of each value
    for (var i in a) { //iterate the array of values
        var b = a[i].split('='); //separate the key and value pair
        query[decodeURIComponent(b[0])] = decodeURIComponent(b[1]); //call decodeURIComponent to sanitize the query string
    }

    return query; //returned the parsed query string object
}

function buildQuery(obj){
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj) //iterate the query object
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) { //check if the object has the propery name we're iterating
           str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p])); //push the encoded key value pair from the object into  the string array
       }
    return str.join("&"); //take the array of key value pairs and join them on &
}
```

Then below we take the string that you gave, for example:

```
var $str = 'createimage&t1=1412757517&t2=1412843917&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=SCP-3&service=MODIFICATION+TIME+EDR+FILES&backtrack=4&zoom=4';
```

Now we call the parseQuery function on our string.

```
var obj = parseQuery($str);
```

Then we iterate the object which was produced from our parseQuery function

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k, i) {
    switch(k){
        case 't1':
            obj[k] = 'replacedt1';
            break;
        case 'service':
            obj[k] = 'replacedServices';
            break;
        case 'host':
            obj[k] = 'replacedHost';
    }         
});
```

Now the `obj` variable has the newly updated values. We can rebuild the query using our `buildQuery` function by passing the object in.

```
console.log(buildQuery(obj));
```

Which will produce something like:

```
createimage=undefined&t1=replacedt1&t2=1412843917&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=replacedHost&service=replacedServices&backtrack=4&zoom=4
```

[As usual, the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10q78q47/)

Comment: the part "Then we iterate the object.." sounds a bit weird. You can simply do `obj.host="replacedHost"`, `obj.service="replacedService"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Played with JavaScript a bit, I believe this solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dk48vwz7/

```
var linktext = "http://site/some-url/trends.cgi?createimage&t1=1412757517&t2=1412843917&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=SCP-3&service=MODIFICATION+TIME+EDR+FILES&backtrack=4&zoom=4";

//we'll use an in-memory "hyperlink" object for basic parsing
var anchor = document.createElement("A");
anchor.href=linktext;

//the query string starts with ?, we remove it. 
//then, split it by & symbol
var queryvars = anchor.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');

//now looping through all parts of query string, creating an object in form key->value
var querycontent = {};
for( i = 0; i < queryvars.length; i++ ) {
    var queryvar = queryvars[i].split('=');
    querycontent[queryvar[0]] = queryvar[1];
}

//this allows us to reference parts of the query as properties of "querycontent" variable
querycontent.service = "AnotherService"
//TODO: change the properties you actually need

//and now putting it all back together
var querymerged = [];
var g = "";
for (var key in querycontent){
    var fragment = key;
    if (querycontent[key]) {
        fragment += "=" + querycontent[key];
    }
    querymerged.push(fragment);
}
anchor.search = querymerged.join("&")

//finally, access the `href` property of anchor to get the link you need
document.getElementById("test").innerText=anchor.href;
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wants to do this in JS, not PHP.(question seems poorly tagged, to be fair)

Comment: that's what happens when the question has wrong tags + it is not completed before it's submitted :-)

Comment: :grins: I was just editing comment to acknowledge poor tags - you beat me to it. :)

Comment: can i just insert variables in base URL? like //some-url/createimage&t1-$variable1/yes&initialassumedhoststate-$variable2 (where variable = my input) and redirect to new URL ?

Comment: Please update your answer now that you realize it's not a question related to PHP. Right now it's kind of confusing because you start your answer with PHP methods. Your fiddle is still useful so I feel the answer itself should not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `URL` object (for older browsers, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/url.js)) :

```
var url = new URL("http://some-url/trends.cgi?createimage&t1=1412757517&t2=1412843917&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=SCP-3&service=MODIFICATION+TIME+EDR+FILES&backtrack=4&zoom=4");
url.searchParams.set("t1", "someNewT1");
url.searchParams.set("t2", "someNewT2");
url.searchParams.set("host", "someNewHost");
url.searchParams.set("service", "someNewService");

alert(url.href);
/*
http://some-url/trends.cgi?host=someNewHost&assumestateretention=yes&initialassumedservicestate=0&t2=someNewT2&initialassumedhoststate=0&assumeinitialstates=yes&zoom=4&backtrack=4&createimage=&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&includesoftstates=no&service=someNewService&t1=someNewT1
*/
```

Comment: can i just insert variables in base URL? like //some-url/createimage&t1-$variable1/yes&initialassumedhoststate-$variable2 (where variable = my input) and redirect to new URL ?

Comment: @dend The `set` method takes a string, so yes, you can insert or concatenate any cariable into it.

Comment: Can u give me some example please